# Virtualhost with two dashes

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, hostname

I am facing a problem with defining virtual host, if I define host like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName some-site-name.example.com
    DocumentRoot /data/web
</VirtualHost>
```

It does not work and redirects to top virtual host.
But if I define it like this

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName some-sitename.example.com
        DocumentRoot /data/web
</VirtualHost>
```

So I was able to track the cause of it being two dashes in the hostname. I tried enabling
Hostname lookups in apache config, but that did not help either.

Can I somehow escape the dashes so apache picks it up?

Comment: There must be something else at play. There is no such restriction for the `ServerName` in Apache.

Comment: The order of those `VHost` declarations matter.